# return a value in a loop before continuing a loop: goroutines, mutex or channels?

Tags: go, mutex, channel, goroutine

My database structure contains the following fields: `catalog.id`, `catalog.category_id`, `catalog.name` and its related field, `category.name` and `category.id` .

While importing csv records containing fields of `csv_category_name` and `csv_catalog_name`using golang, as the loop starts I want to check if `csv_category_name` exists in the field `category.name` and return its  value to be inserted in `catalog.category_id` otherwise, create a `category.name` and return `category.id` retain the value in the memory so it can be inserted into catalog.cateogory_id in the rest of the loop with a similar condition before the loop continues

i believe there could be an easier way but with my limited knowledge in golang,  I have drafted a code and i believe with your suggestion i can provide a better result

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    cname := models.Category{
        CategoryName: c.Name, // this to be picked from loop
    }
    bb, err := models.CategoryByID(db, 4)
    if err != nil {
        cname.Save(db)
        return cname
    }

    for {
        var c CatalogCSV

        //CheckorCreate when the loop starts and use the value in the rest of the loop

        if err := dec.Decode(&c); err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        a := models.Catalog{
            CatalogName:         c.Catalogname,
            CatalogCategoryName: c.Categoryname, // This is part of the initial CSV file
            CataloCategoryID:    b.ID,           // this is to be picked from CategoryByID
        }

        // save author to database
        err = a.Save(db)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```